# Remove autosuggestion in FF quantum using about config

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

How do you stop quantum 58 in about config from showing the drop down suggestion box every time i want to look for something.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do you stop Firefox from showing the drop down suggestion box?

> 1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click the button promising to be careful.
> 2. In the search box above the list, type or paste `URLB` and pause while the list is filtered
> 3. If the `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled` preference is not bolded and still has its default value of `true`, at least one of
>      these must still also be set to true:
>
>    - `browser.urlbar.suggest.bookmark`
>    - `browser.urlbar.suggest.history`
>    - `browser.urlbar.suggest.openpage`
>    - `browser.urlbar.suggest.searches`
>
> If you double-click the `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled preference`to flip its value from `true` to `false`, all four of those should also switch to `false`.

Source [How to completely disable the drop-down menu in the address bar? | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1173445#answer-1001910)